# Deserialize a strange JSON array with newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I'm normally able to deserialize a JSON array, but in a webservice response I founded a particular array. 
I'm not able to deserialize it because I have not a defined name for each array item, but a different list of dates. I created a class, but after deserialization it is empty because I don't know how to refer to each item.
Could you help me to find a solution? 
Thanks!!!

```
{
"daily_rates": {
          "2020-05-01": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-02": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-03": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-04": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-05": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-06": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-07": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-08": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ],
          "2020-05-31": [
            {
              "rate_id": "1",
              "rate_name": "Soggiorno e prima colazione (BB)",
              "cost": 205,
              "minlos": 1
            }
          ]
        }
}
```

Comment: which language are you using on server side? Java? ahh nevermind newtonsoft is .NET so its C # I guess

Comment: I'm using VB.Net and newstonsoft library

Comment: It has an invalid type, you have to create properties with it has different dates and different rates on it, the properties must match so can be converted

Comment: This kind of JSON is often treated as a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of [class]))`. So you can have a Root object with a Property named `"daily_rates"` of type `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of [class]))`, where `[class]` is a class object with properties `rate_id`, `rate_name` etc. You can also directly use `DateTime` instead of `String` as the Dictionary key: the conversion is automatic.

Comment: Of course the keys must be unique. If there's a chance they're not, you need a custom converter, otherwise the last non-unique `DateTime`/`String` key will overwrite all previous values.

Comment: Thank guys. I will try with Dictionary and let you know. For me, this JSON is not correct.. Web Service developers should create a property named for example rDate, non directly the date...

Comment: Thanks @Jimi. Solved using Dictionary()

`code`
        Public Class Get_Rooms_Rates_Details
            Public daily_rates As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Get_Rooms_Rates_Default_Rates))

        End Class

        Public Class Get_Rooms_Rates_Default_Rates
            Public rate_id As String
            Public rate_name As String
            Public cost As Decimal
        End Class
`code`

Comment: @Arkadoo post it as an answer to your question